# Guide line for Regex to validate input

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i want to validate a input by regex. if user enter any character with in a to z or A to Z then it will not accepted but if user enter + sign or bracket or any digit then it will be accepted. i use the regex but it did not work as per my requirement.

```
var regEx = '/^[A-Za-z]*$/';
            if (flag) {
                var val = jQuery.trim($("input[id*='txtfphone']").val())
                if (val.match(regEx)) {
                    if (_AdjustHeight == 0) {
                        $(".ui-dialog").animate({ height: '+=' + dialog_loader.height + 'px' }, 600, function () {
                            _AdjustHeight = 1;
                            $('#feed_loader').fadeIn('slow').html('<span>' + dialog_Msg.Invalid_Phone + '</span>');
                            $("input[id*='txtfphone']").focus()
                        });
                    }
                    else if (_AdjustHeight == 1) {
                        $('#feed_loader').fadeOut('slow', function () {
                            $('#feed_loader').html('<span>' + dialog_Msg.Invalid_Phone + '</span>');
                        }).fadeIn('slow');

                        $("input[id*='txtfphone']").focus()
                    }
                    flag = false;
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

so help me with right regex. 
it will be accepted if user enter data like

```
+913325806589
+91 33 25806589
913325806589
91 33 25806589
91 (33) 25806589
+91 (33) 25806589
```

but if user enter any alphabet as a input then it will not be accepted. like

```
aaab
+a913325806589
+91332a5806589
+91332a5806589b etc
```

a to z any character will not be accepted. thanks

Comment: for the the `/^[A-Za-z]*$/`, are you trying to match the invalid case?

Comment: One should **not** ignore this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/123559)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does this one meets your need?

```
var regEx = /^\+?\d+[\d\s]*(\s*\(\d+\)\s*\d*)*$/ //no quote !!
```

for your

```
var regEx = '/^[A-Za-z]*$/'
```

you have defined the `regEx` to a string, so it won't take any effect.

Comment: i use your regex but postback occur i think there is some problem.here is my code where i use it.var 
regEx = '^\+?\d+[\d\s]*(\s*\(\d+\)\s*\d*)*$'; var val = jQuery.trim($("input[id*='txtfphone']").val()) if (!val.match(regEx)) { //not valid } what is wrong here?

Comment: what's your `val()` of `input[id*='txtfphone']`?

Comment: val() return txtfphone value whatever user input. so the variable val will contain the phone number like +913365209874 etc

Comment: please check [here](http://regex101.com/r/xP0wL6), i think the "+913365209874" should be valid. what's the problem you got?

Comment: the moment i put your regex then error occur. jquery is not giving the error message.

Comment: @Thomas `var regEx = '^\+?\d+[\d\s]*(\s*(\d+)\s*\d*)*$'` is wrong, in this case regEx is just a string but not regex ,just `var regEx = /^\+?\d+[\d\s]*(\s*(\d+)\s*\d*)*$/`

Comment: @Thomas updated your [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/terryleonhart/UGar9/2/), check again

Comment: fiddler is not updated i checked. i use ur regex var regEx = '/^[A-Za-z]*$/' but found problem. when i enter abc in phone field them regex did not match. if it would match then i can prevent user to stop putting alphabet or alphanumeric value. if possible have a look. thanks for your effort.

Comment: @Thomas i have updated the answer, have you checked it? your problem is you made your `regEx` to be a string, so it won't match anything. my fiddl is http://jsfiddle.net/terryleonhart/UGar9/2/

Comment: this time it was ok but + sign become mandatory. so please make it option because user may enter + sign or may not. thanks for effort.

Answer (score 0):

The regrex you are using is anchored at both the beginning and end, which means it will only match when the input contains only letters. It would not, for example, match "12a".

It also fails to check for all of the other invalid characters you haven't mentioned... !£#@ etc.

It would be better to use a regex that matches what you do want, and then see if the input fails to match.

From your description and examples, this should match valid input:

```
/^\s*\+?[\d\s]*(\([\d\s]+\)?)[\d\s]*$/
```

You then need to negate your match test:

```
if (!val.match(regEx)) {
```

Comment: i use your regex but postback occur i think there is some problem.here is my code where i use it.var regEx = '/^\s*+?[\d\s](([\d\s]+)?)[\d\s]$/';
var val = jQuery.trim($("input[id*='txtfphone']").val())
if (!val.match(regEx)) { //not valid } what is wrong here?

Comment: What input did you test with?

Comment: the variable val will contain the phone number like +913365209874 etc and i am trying to validate it.